# Inversion of a Fourier-like transformation on $\partial B_1(0)$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis

I have a function $A(x) = \int_{\partial B_1(0)} e^{ikx} B(k) dk$ in $3D$ and I want to find $B(k)$ for a given $A(x)$. How can I do that?

In my use case it would be enough to invert $R_n^m(x) = \int_{\partial B_1(0)} e^{ikx} S_n^m(k) dk$ with $R \in \mathrm{SO}(3; \mathbb R)$, $\forall x$. Any help for the special or general case would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It is helpful to rewrite the integral over the surface of the unit sphere into an integral over the whole 3D space, using the delta function $\delta(k-1)$,
$$A(x,y,z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dk_x\int_{-\infty}^\infty dk_y\int_{-\infty}^\infty dk_z \,e^{ik_x x+ik_y y+ik_z z}B(k_x,k_y,k_z)\delta\left(\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2+k_z^2}-1\right).$$
Inversion of the Fourier transform gives
$$B(k_x,k_y,k_z)\delta\left(\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2+k_z^2}-1\right)=(2\pi)^{-3}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy\int_{-\infty}^\infty dz\,e^{-ik_x x-ik_y y-ik_z z}A(x,y,z).$$
Integration over the radial coordinate then produces the function $B$ itself, as a function of the angular coordinates.